# IE9L Automatically changing Document Mode to IE7

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

This is the worst ... for some reason, my application is not working correctly because IE9 things that it's IE7 and automatically changes the Document Mode to IE7.

It's a really odd situation, because my PC does NOT do this. But it seems to be that those who have upgraded their IE from 7 or 8 to 9 get this behaviour... compatibility mode?

I have no idea what to do to ensure that IE renders the document properly!

[image]

Some more information on the matter ... it is absolutely because of Compatibility Mode. When this mode is turned on, the screenshot above applies. But when Developer Tools are opened, everything works.

---

NOTE: I just read somewhere that IE will not be able to process `console.log()` and this could be the issue! Is this possible?

Comment: It's IE, what can you expect :P

Comment: Yes, well although I share your sentiments, it really hurts the success of my application.

Comment: I'm sorry I really have no idea i'm nearly clueless about web design :( I was just looking around and saw somebody complaining about IE and decided to join the party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` is the issue. Apparently IE just doesn't like it an the scrips will die. Remove all references to `console.log` and all is well.

Answer (score 5):

Trying setting this meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

I use google chrome frame for IE8 and below with

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=IE8">
```

Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx and http://456bereastreet.com/archive/201103/x-ua-compatible_and_html5

Edit:  as pocesar said in the comments your doctype is set incorrectly also, it should be

```
<!doctype html>
```

Comment: I've got `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">` and that does not seem to do anything

Comment: @dcolumbus Make sure it comes **before** any script tags. I'd even make it the first tag after the opening `<head>` tag. Also, why would you use `IE=9` instead of `IE=edge`? If you don't know what this does, why would you not use the answer above?

Comment: It needs to be the absolute first tag in the head section.

Comment: Ive done it through .htaccess ... that seems to force the issue, but my application (AJAX) still will not work. But as soon as I open Developer Tools, it works.

Comment: I just read somewhere that IE will not be able to process `console.log()` and this could be the issue! Is this possible?

Comment: through htaccess it would be `<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" </IfModule>` and it should work for any request. AJAX won't need it, since the DOCTYPE doesn't matter INSIDE the ajax response, but in the page only. Make sure you didn't click the "compatibility" button near the URL bar as well.

Comment: also, you doctype looks bogus, it should be `<!doctype html>` that is triggering quirks mode

Comment: I had the same problem. Adding the "IE=edge" meta tag worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My site's document mode is changed to "IE5" automatically by IE11. I was able to solve it dong the following, I hope this is useful to somebody.

I can't explain why, but if I place the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` **after** the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`, nothing happens, IE11 renders my site as IE5.

BUT, If i place the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` **before** the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`, it works, my site's document mode is the latest one.

Comment: What has worked for me is adding the meta tag '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />' as the first item inside the '<head>'.

Answer (score 1):

your doctype should be

```
<!doctype html>
```

and not `<!-- DOCTYPE html -->`, that defeats the use of the `UA-Compatible` tag

plus, you should place the meta tag as

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
```

or inside your .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c> 
  Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" 
</IfModule>
```

(these are from HTML5 Boilerplate http://html5boilerplate.com/)